# userId is always evaluating to null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I added a property to ApplicationUser in the identityModel class so as to extend it like this

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        **public ICollection<Posts> post { get; set; }**

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

which is to refer to the fact that a user can have many posts. My Post.cs class looks like this

```
public class Posts
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid PostId { get; set; }

        public string PostTitle { get; set; }

        public string PostContent { get; set; }

        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }


        public virtual ApplicationUser appUser { get; set; }
    }
```

the last line of code there is refering to the fact that a post belongs to a user.
However,in my post controller to create a post,i use

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PostTitle,PostContent")] Posts posts)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var posting = new PostVM();


                posts.PostId = Guid.NewGuid();
                posts.PostTitle = posting.PostTitle;
                posts.PostContent = posting.PostTitle;
                posts.PostDate = DateTime.Now;
                var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
                string username = currentUser.UserName; //** get UserName
                Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;//** get user ID
                posts.appUser.Id = userGuid.ToString();
                db.Post.Add(posts);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(posts);
        }
```

The problem is that the "posts.appUser.Id" field is always evaluating as null when i try to save to database. What can i do?

Comment: By using the `Bind` attribute you have enabled only the `PostTitle` and `PostContent` properties of your `Posts` model to be populated. So I don't understand how can you possibly expect that `posts.appUser.Id` would get some value different than `null`? You explicitly exclude it from model binding and then expect to get some value from it?

Answer (score 0):

You have no explicit foreign key property for your `ApplicationUser` relationship, so the only to save it along with `Post` is to lookup up the user from the database and set the `appUser` property to that.

In that regard, you've got some serious problems here as it appears you're trying to mix and match Identity and ASP.NET Membership. They're two completely different systems that are incompatible with each other. To get the `ApplicationUser` instance corresponding to the currently authenticated user from your database, you need to do:

```
var user = UserManager.GetById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

All of the `Membership.*` family of methods won't work here.

Comment: how do i add an explicit foreign key property to the ApplicationUser. Do i just add [ForeignKey] data annotation to the ICollection<Posts> post property? And also i used the code you wrote like this var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                     posts.appUser.Id = user;    and i got the error "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I wasnt able to use the UserManager.GetById